# Octobercms Filter scopes options not returned from model class

Tags: backend, octobercms, octobercms-backend

According to Octobercms [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#filter-scope-options) I can get the options from a model class method.

But when I try to filter the list I get an undefined index error.

> "Undefined index: holiday_type" on line 417 of .../modules/backend/Widgets/Filter.php

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the options from a method via model class

**config_filter.yaml**

```
# ===================================
# Filter Scope Definitions
# ===================================

scopes:
    holiday_type:
        label: Holiday Type
        type: group
        conditions: type in (:filtered)
        options: getHolidayTypesAttribute
```

**MyModel.php**

```php
public function getHolidayTypesAttribute(){
    return [
        1 => 'default',
        2 => 'new'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one thing in your config. :) `modelClass`

> You need to specify which model to use for getting option list if your filter type is `group`

```yaml
scopes:
    holiday_type:
        label: Holiday Type
        type: group
        conditions: type in (:filtered)
        options: getHolidayTypesAttribute
        modelClass: Acme\Blog\Models\Category <- you are missing this
```

> Replace `Acme\Blog\Models\Category` with `your model class` and try this it should work

Reference: [October CMS filter scopes options](https://coderecharge.com/october-cms/backend/october-cms-filter-scopes-options)

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Ohh yes that was the issue. Thank you!